# Sabre - BFM v1 REST API - Is booking class tied to passenger or a flight leg

Tags: sabre

The question is on Bargain Finder Max v1 REST API response. We have booking class information at passenger level in the response. But when we search flights we don't mention booking class at passenger level. 
Do we always get same booking class (cabinCode, bookingCode) for all passengers in the itinerary?

x.groupedItineraryResponse.itineraryGroups[0].itineraries[0].pricingInformation[0].fare.passengerInfoList[0].passengerInfo.fareComponents[0].segments[0].segment

```
segments": [
   {
     "segment": {
       "bookingCode": "H",
       "cabinCode": "Y",
       "seatsAvailable": 4,
       "availabilityBreak": true
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Booking class is a subset of the cabin Code.

One Cabin Code can have multiple booking classes depending on the airline.

You get one bookingcode for all passengers as a PNR cant handle multiple bookingcodes for one segment.

**Short answer: Yes its tied to Segments and it is the same across passengers.**

Comment: Is the answer actual for the property "availabilityBreak" too? I mean it is tied to all segments and not for each passenger in part.